# Building live dashboard for app deployed in Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, google-cloud-run

I have a questionnaire web app built with ReactJS, NodeJS and using a PostgreSQL database.

I want to deploy this with Cloud Run.

I want to build a live dashboard fetching data from PostgreSQL but I am not sure which Google tools or chart libraries I should use?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to begin is the GitHub repositories to look for code samples and configurations that use Cloud Run. Google provides some Node JS Cloud Run examples that detail the tools and steps you need to take to get started with. You are free to use these as a foundation for your own projects.

[Nodejs Cloud Run Samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/run)